# Obtener los valores por defecto de una función

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

tengo una función `f` con algunos valores por defecto, en otras palabras

```
def my_funct(a, b, c=0, d=None):
    pass
```

Cómo obtengo los valores por defecto de la función. Hay un `__dict__` o algo por el estilo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `__defaults__` obtienes una tupla con los valores por defecto:

```
def my_funct(a, b, c=0, d=None):
    print(c, d)

my_funct(1, 2)

print(my_funct.__defaults__)  # Devuelve (0, None)
```

Si quieres un diccionario con los valores, puedes meter lo siguiente:

```
def my_funct(a, b, *e, c=0, d=None):
    print(c, d)

my_funct(1, 2)

print(my_funct.__kwdefaults__)  # De vuelve {'c': 0, 'd': None}
```

Comment: Y puedo obtener el nombre de cada una de argumentos enlístalos en la función ?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres, quieres obtener las claves en vez de los valores?

Comment: Esperaba más obtener un diccionario donde las llaves fueran los nombres de las variables enlístalos en la función, y los valores fueran los valores por defecto.

Comment: A ver si te vale con lo que he editado

Comment: Perfecto ! Muchas gracias. Una última pregunta, es posible obtener los nombres de las variables que no tienen variables por defecto, en este caso, `a` y `b` ?

Comment: Con my_funct.__code__.co_varnames obtienes todos, no sé si habrá una forma directa de obtener solo esos dos, de todas formas, puedes poner otra pregunta nueva ya que es diferente a esta, que seguro que alguien conocerá la manera.

Comment: Tienes razón. Muchas gracias por la respuesta.